Launch multiple server apps in localhost with different port numbers within the same container in Cloud Run
I'm creating a webapp with 2 main services: Flask and Chainlit.
When I launch my webapp locally on localhost:8080, on my landing page, when I click on the "chat" button, it redirects me to my second service chainlit, which is an AI chatbot (there are many other functionalities in the app). Here's how I launch my two services in production:
Flask: poetry run gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 src.app.app:app
Chainlit: poetry run chainlit run --headless src/chatbot.py
When I build my docker image and launch my container locally, everything works perfectly with the 2 ports exposed. But it doesn't work on Cloud Run. Here are the contents of my files :

app.py
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/chat")
def chat():
    return redirect("http://localhost:8000")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)


Dockerfile
FROM ollama/ollama

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

# Update package list and install pipx
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y ffmpeg && \
    apt-get install -y pipx && \
    pipx install poetry==1.7.1 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container
COPY . .

# Install dependencies with poetry
RUN poetry install --no-root --no-cache --without explo && \
    chmod +x pull_ollama_models_and_launch_app_servers.sh

EXPOSE 8080 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["./pull_ollama_models_and_launch_app_servers.sh"]



#!/bin/bash

# Start Ollama in the background.
ollama serve &

# Pause for Ollama to start.
sleep 5

# Pause before server launch
echo " Launching Servers (Flask and Chainlit) ..."
sleep 5

# Start Chainlit
poetry run chainlit run --headless src/chatbot.py &

# start flask landing page
poetry run gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 src.app.app:app &


# Wait for both background processes to exit
wait



My problem is that on Cloud Run, the landing page (index.html) works fine when I access the application via the generated URL. However, the chat part doesn't work at all (This site can’t be reached error). Default STARTUP TCP probe succeeded after 1 attempt for container "xxx" on port 8080 is the only stack-trace available on the log, no trace of chainlit service running on port 8000.
Can anyone help me?

Typical Docker practice is to run only one process in a container.  In your setup, if one server or the other fails for whatever reason, you have no way of easily noticing; if you have two separate containers, though, the container runtime can restart them.  Can you split these out?

As it seems that splitting them in 2 separate container is only solution, I'll give it a try !
But what is the best way to do that automatically as I plan to build them in future using Github Actions?  Should I use Docker compose or something else ?

Cloud Run always exposes 1 port. If you want to have another port available outside your container, you need to deploy it as a cloud run sidecar.
EXPOSE 8080 8000 will be overwritten as EXPOSE $PORT by cloud run

I've already seen Sidecar, I just thought it's a little bit more complex than my initial architecture. So I was wondering if there is another solution. I tried also nginx reverse-proxy like in this article, but it doesn't fit my use case : https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-multiple-processes-easy-way/

There is no other solution. You can't expose more ports in the container deployed by Cloud Run.

On another look into this, your approach should also be working to be honest. Are you sure that poetry is running on port 8000?
